# tablix columns jagged in dynamics crm report viewer

Tags: reporting-services, report, dynamics-crm-2011

In Dynamic CRM 2011, I've developed a report that works fine in BIDS and even show data perfectly while extracting to a pdf file but in CRM report viewer its columns jagged towards right. I tried a lot but unable to find the problem.

I need your guidance to resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you getting any warning error messages in the report layout? Sometimes overlapping fields can cause this sort of misalignment

Comment: no, I am not getting any layout error. Not even fields are overlapping. Here is what I am facing only in report viewer in CRM:

https://community.dynamics.com/cfs-file/__key/communityserver-discussions-components-files/117/image002.jpg

Comment: How does your report look when you export it to Excel?

Comment: It looks fine without any jagged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2864250) post by Microsoft support helped me to resolve this issue.